# Cmake throws error during generation when building openpose library

Tags: cmake

I am very new to cmake and I am using Cmake Gui for compiling the openpose library https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose. When I configure it, it configures successfully but when I click generate, it throws error but still generates compiled files. I am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC9GTb6Wsb4 this tutorial, but when I try to build the program using visual studio, I get error.

I have installed Visual studio 2017 in windows 10 with Nvidia Geforce 940M.[Visual Studio screenshot after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laUXA.png)

```
  Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.
CMAKE_VERSION = 3.17.0-rc1
Building with CUDA.
Downloading windows dependencies...
opencv_411_v14_15_2019_09_24.zip already exists.
caffe3rdparty_15_2019_03_14.zip already exists.
caffe_15_2019_05_16.zip already exists.
Windows dependencies downloaded.
Adding Example Calibration
Adding Example OpenPoseDemo
Adding Example 1_custom_post_processing
Adding Example 01_body_from_image_default
Adding Example 02_whole_body_from_image_default
Adding Example 03_keypoints_from_image
Adding Example 04_keypoints_from_images
Adding Example 05_keypoints_from_images_multi_gpu
Adding Example 06_face_from_image
Adding Example 07_hand_from_image
Adding Example 08_heatmaps_from_image
Adding Example 09_keypoints_from_heatmaps
Adding Example 10_asynchronous_custom_input
Adding Example 11_asynchronous_custom_output
Adding Example 12_asynchronous_custom_input_output_and_datum
Adding Example 13_synchronous_custom_input
Adding Example 14_synchronous_custom_preprocessing
Adding Example 15_synchronous_custom_postprocessing
Adding Example 16_synchronous_custom_output
Adding Example 17_synchronous_custom_all_and_datum
Adding Example 1_thread_user_processing_function
Adding Example 2_thread_user_input_processing_output_and_datum
Download the models.
Downloading BODY_25 model...
Model already exists.
Not downloading body (COCO) model
Not downloading body (MPI) model
Downloading face model...
Model already exists.
Downloading hand model...
Model already exists.
Models Downloaded.
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

pybind11 v2.4.dev4
Configuring done
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:1833 (add_library):
  Target "openpose" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/openpose/CMakeLists.txt:21 (cuda_add_library)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:1833 (add_library):
  Target "openpose" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/openpose/CMakeLists.txt:21 (cuda_add_library)


CMake Error at examples/calibration/CMakeLists.txt:15 (add_executable):
  Target "Calibration" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/calibration/CMakeLists.txt:15 (add_executable):
  Target "Calibration" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/openpose/CMakeLists.txt:15 (add_executable):
  Target "OpenPoseDemo" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/openpose/CMakeLists.txt:15 (add_executable):
  Target "OpenPoseDemo" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_add_module/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "1_custom_post_processing" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_add_module/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "1_custom_post_processing" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "01_body_from_image_default" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "01_body_from_image_default" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "02_whole_body_from_image_default" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "02_whole_body_from_image_default" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "08_heatmaps_from_image" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "08_heatmaps_from_image" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "03_keypoints_from_image" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "03_keypoints_from_image" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "12_asynchronous_custom_input_output_and_datum" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "12_asynchronous_custom_input_output_and_datum" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "05_keypoints_from_images_multi_gpu" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "05_keypoints_from_images_multi_gpu" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "04_keypoints_from_images" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "04_keypoints_from_images" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "06_face_from_image" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "06_face_from_image" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "07_hand_from_image" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "07_hand_from_image" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "09_keypoints_from_heatmaps" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "09_keypoints_from_heatmaps" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "10_asynchronous_custom_input" links to target "Threads::Threads"
  but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
  an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "10_asynchronous_custom_input" links to target "Threads::Threads"
  but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
  an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "11_asynchronous_custom_output" links to target "Threads::Threads"
  but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
  an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "11_asynchronous_custom_output" links to target "Threads::Threads"
  but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
  an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "13_synchronous_custom_input" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "13_synchronous_custom_input" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "17_synchronous_custom_all_and_datum" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "17_synchronous_custom_all_and_datum" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "14_synchronous_custom_preprocessing" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "14_synchronous_custom_preprocessing" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "15_synchronous_custom_postprocessing" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "15_synchronous_custom_postprocessing" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "16_synchronous_custom_output" links to target "Threads::Threads"
  but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
  an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "16_synchronous_custom_output" links to target "Threads::Threads"
  but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
  an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_thread/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_executable):
  Target "1_thread_user_processing_function" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_thread/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_executable):
  Target "1_thread_user_processing_function" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_thread/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_executable):
  Target "2_thread_user_input_processing_output_and_datum" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_thread/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_executable):
  Target "2_thread_user_input_processing_output_and_datum" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at 3rdparty/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:131 (add_library):
  Target "pyopenpose" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  python/openpose/CMakeLists.txt:6 (pybind11_add_module)


CMake Error at 3rdparty/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:131 (add_library):
  Target "pyopenpose" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  python/openpose/CMakeLists.txt:6 (pybind11_add_module)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:1833 (add_library):
  Target "openpose" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/openpose/CMakeLists.txt:21 (cuda_add_library)


CMake Error at examples/calibration/CMakeLists.txt:15 (add_executable):
  Target "Calibration" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/openpose/CMakeLists.txt:15 (add_executable):
  Target "OpenPoseDemo" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_add_module/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "1_custom_post_processing" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "01_body_from_image_default" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "02_whole_body_from_image_default" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "08_heatmaps_from_image" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "03_keypoints_from_image" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "12_asynchronous_custom_input_output_and_datum" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "05_keypoints_from_images_multi_gpu" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "04_keypoints_from_images" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "06_face_from_image" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "07_hand_from_image" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "09_keypoints_from_heatmaps" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "10_asynchronous_custom_input" links to target "Threads::Threads"
  but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
  an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "11_asynchronous_custom_output" links to target "Threads::Threads"
  but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
  an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "13_synchronous_custom_input" links to target "Threads::Threads" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "17_synchronous_custom_all_and_datum" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "14_synchronous_custom_preprocessing" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "15_synchronous_custom_postprocessing" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "16_synchronous_custom_output" links to target "Threads::Threads"
  but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
  an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_thread/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_executable):
  Target "1_thread_user_processing_function" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at examples/tutorial_api_thread/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_executable):
  Target "2_thread_user_input_processing_output_and_datum" links to target
  "Threads::Threads" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package()
  call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at 3rdparty/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:131 (add_library):
  Target "pyopenpose" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  python/openpose/CMakeLists.txt:6 (pybind11_add_module)


Generating done
```

This is the log of cmake when I configure and generate.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your CMake contained errors during generation so you should not attempt to build Visual Studio yet. It looks like openpose (or more likely, one of its dependencies such as OpenCV or Caffe) could not find a Thread library on your machine. If you re-configure CMake from scratch, is there an error showing `Threads` not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version v3.17.0-rc1~455^2 of CMake introduced the use of the
`Threads::Threads` target, but it does not use `find_package(Threads)` on all
platforms. To correct for this, make the following [changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43AZl.png) to your FindCUDA.cmake file, located in C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.17\Modules

Alternatively, you can replace the file with the one found at https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake

Comment: Thanks! It compiles and generates without any errors now.