# Building OpenCV 4.1.1 with CUDA 10.2 Threads::Threads error

Tags: opencv, cmake, dependencies

I'm trying to generate VS2019 project on Windows 10 64-bit with CMake GUI 3.17.0 rc.

Here is my full config:

```
Detected processor: AMD64
libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 2.0.2, BUILD = opencv-4.1.1-libjpeg-turbo
Found TBB (cmake): C:/Program Files/TBB/bin/intel64/vc14/tbb.dll
found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2019.0.0 [2019.0.0 Gold]
at: C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2019.0.0
at: C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
CUDA detected: 10.2
CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-D_FORCE_INLINES
LAPACK(LAPACK/Generic): LAPACK_LIBRARIES: C:/Users/corsair/Anaconda3/Library/lib/lapack.lib;C:/Users/corsair/Anaconda3/Library/lib/blas.lib
LAPACK(LAPACK/Generic): Support is enabled.
Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/build/python_loader
Caffe:   NO
Protobuf:   NO
Glog:   NO
freetype2:   NO
harfbuzz:    NO
Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Glog/Gflags
Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
Tesseract:   NO
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake:54 (message):
  CONFIGURATION IS NOT SUPPORTED: validate setupvars script in install
  directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1059 (include)



General configuration for OpenCV 4.1.1 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            C:/Program Files/opencv_contrib-4.1.1/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2020-08-29T09:07:38Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.17763 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.17.0-rc1
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 16 2019
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1923

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (13 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (27 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (2 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.23.28105.4)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP12   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP12   /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast       /MP12    /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast       /MP12  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO 
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          cudart_static.lib Threads::Threads C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/lib/x64/cuda.lib nppc.lib nppial.lib nppicc.lib nppicom.lib nppidei.lib nppif.lib nppig.lib nppim.lib nppist.lib nppisu.lib nppitc.lib npps.lib cublas.lib cuda cufft.lib -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/lib/x64 -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot quality reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    python3 python_tests world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cvv freetype java js matlab ovis python2 sfm viz
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         YES

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.2-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.35.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.20.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.22.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.3.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2020.3 interface 11103)

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2019.0.0 Gold [2019.0.0]
           at:                   C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2019.0.0)
              at:                C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      YES (C:/Users/corsair/Anaconda3/Library/lib/lapack.lib C:/Users/corsair/Anaconda3/Library/lib/blas.lib)
    Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.7)
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.2, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             61
    NVIDIA PTX archs:

  cuDNN:                         YES (ver 7.6.5)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python (for build):            C:/Users/corsair/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/build/install
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
```

After pressing Generate the following errors occur:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1445 (add_library):
  Target "opencv_cudev" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:930 (ocv_add_library)
  C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:851 (_ocv_create_module)
  C:/Program Files/opencv_contrib-4.1.1/modules/cudev/CMakeLists.txt:21 (ocv_create_module)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1445 (add_library):
  Target "opencv_cudev" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:930 (ocv_add_library)
  C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:851 (_ocv_create_module)
  C:/Program Files/opencv_contrib-4.1.1/modules/cudev/CMakeLists.txt:21 (ocv_create_module)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1445 (add_library):
  Target "opencv_cudev" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:930 (ocv_add_library)
  C:/Program Files/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:851 (_ocv_create_module)
  C:/Program Files/opencv_contrib-4.1.1/modules/cudev/CMakeLists.txt:21 (ocv_create_module)
```

and so on...

I guess with this errors it wouldn't compile properly. Searching with key words `Threads::Threads` didn't lead to a solution.  Please, help if you have any ideas how to fix this

Actually, it's not the first time compiling OpenCV on my machine, but the very first trying to add CUDA support

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60480361/950131. If indeed CUDA related, then upgrade to at least CMake 3.18.2 might help. Alternatively adding find_package(Threads REQUIRED) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with new software configuration:

- VS2017,
- CUDA 10.0
- CMake3.17.0 rc
- openCV 4.1.1 & opencv-contrib 4.1.1

I also used CMake and Windows command line instaed of Cmake GUI. Here is the full list of changes and parameters I set up (maybe it will be helpful for someone)

```
set "opencvSource=opencv-4.1.1-cuda"
set "opencvExtraModules=opencv_contrib-4.1.1/modules"
set "opencvBuild=%opencvSource%\build"
set "compiler=Visual Studio 16 2019"
set "buildType=Release"

set "python2_executable=C:/Python27/python.exe"
set "python2_include_dir=C:/Python27/include"
set "python2_library=C:/Python27/libs/python27.lib"
set "python2_numpy_include_dirs=C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include"
set "python2_packages_path=C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages"

set "python3_executable=C:/Python37/python.exe"
set "python3_include_dir=C:/Python37/include"
set "python3_library=C:/Python37/libs/python37.lib"
set "python3_numpy_include_dirs=C:/Python37/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include"
set "python3_packages_path=C:/Python37/Lib/site-packages"

set "cudnnLibrary=C:/Program Files/cuda"
set "cudnnInclude=C:/Program Files/cuda/include"

cmake ^
-B"%opencvBuild%/" ^
-H"%opencvSource%/" ^
-G"%compiler%" ^
-Ax64 ^
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=%buildType% ^
-DBUILD_opencv_world=OFF ^
-DINSTALL_TESTS=OFF ^
-DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF ^
-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ^
-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH="%opencvExtraModules%/" ^
-DBUILD_PROTOBUF=OFF ^
-DBUILD_opencv_python_bindings_generator=ON ^
-DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON ^
-DENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON ^
-DWITH_CUDA=ON ^
-DCUDA_ARCH_BIN=6.1 ^
-DCUDA_FAST_MATH=ON ^
-DWITH_CUBLAS=ON ^
-DCUDA_ARCH_PTX=7.5 ^
-DBUILD_opencv_python2=ON ^
-DPYTHON2_EXECUTABLE="%python2_executable%" ^
-DOPENCV_PYTHON2_VERSION=2.7.16 ^
-DPYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR="%python2_include_dir%" ^
-DPYTHON2_LIBRARY="%python2_library%" ^
-DPYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS="%python2_numpy_include_dirs%" ^
-DPYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH="%python2_packages_path%" ^
-DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON ^
-DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE="%python3_executable%" ^
-DOPENCV_PYTHON3_VERSION=3.7.3 ^
-DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR="%python3_include_dir%" ^
-DPYTHON3_LIBRARY="%python3_library%" ^
-DPYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS="%python3_numpy_include_dirs%" ^
-DPYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH="%python3_packages_path%"


-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.1.1 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
--
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            C:/OpenCV/opencv_contrib-4.1.1/modules
--     Version control (extra):     unknown
--
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2020-08-30T21:24:19Z
--     Host:                        Windows 10.0.17763 AMD64
--     CMake:                       3.18.2
--     CMake generator:             Visual Studio 16 2019
--     CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe
--     MSVC:                        1923
--
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (15 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (29 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (5 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.23.28105.4)
--     C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP12   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP12   /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
--     C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
--     C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast       /MP12    /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast       /MP12  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
--     Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO
--     Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          cudart_static.lib C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.0/lib/x64/cuda.lib nppc.lib nppial.lib nppicc.lib nppicom.lib nppidei.lib nppif.lib nppig.lib nppim.lib nppist.lib nppisu.lib nppitc.lib npps.lib cublas.lib cudnn.lib cufft.lib -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.0/lib/x64
--     3rdparty dependencies:
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python2 python3 quality reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab world xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
--     Disabled:                    -
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cvv freetype java js matlab ovis sfm viz
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         YES
--
--   Windows RT support:            NO
--
--   GUI:
--     Win32 UI:                    YES
--     VTK support:                 NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.2-62)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
--       avcodec:                   YES (58.35.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (58.20.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (56.22.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (5.3.100)
--       avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     DirectShow:                  YES
--     Media Foundation:            YES
--       DXVA:                      YES
--
--   Parallel framework:            Concurrency
--
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2019.0.0 Gold [2019.0.0]
--            at:                   C:/OpenCV/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2019.0.0)
--               at:                C:/OpenCV/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
--     Lapack:                      YES (C:/Users/corsair/Anaconda3/Library/lib/lapack.lib C:/Users/corsair/Anaconda3/Library/lib/blas.lib)
--     Eigen:                       NO
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
--
--   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.0, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             61
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:            75
--
--   cuDNN:                         YES (ver 7.6.2)
--
--   OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
--     Include path:                C:/OpenCV/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
--
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 C:/Python27/python.exe (ver 2.7.16)
--     Libraries:                   C:/Python27/libs/python27.lib (ver 2.7.16)
--     numpy:                       C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.16.6)
--     install path:                C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/cv2/python-2.7
--
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 C:/Python37/python.exe (ver 3.7.3)
--     Libraries:                   C:/Python37/libs/python37.lib (ver 3.7.3)
--     numpy:                       C:/Python37/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.19.1)
--     install path:                C:/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cv2/python-3.7
--
--   Python (for build):            C:/Python27/python.exe
--
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
--
--   Install to:                    C:/OpenCV/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/build/install
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/OpenCV/opencv-4.1.1-cuda/build
```